# C++ Return list inside a std::pair

Tags: c++, list, stdlist

I have several elements held in a `std::list`. I have to output something like `std::pair<int, std::list<std::string> >`. For the int I just add the int variable in directly to the pair. Is there any way to print the list in one statement without having to use iterators? How do you do that inside a pair?

Comment: Why don't you want to use iterators?

Comment: You could `copy` to an `ostream_iterator`...

Comment: So you want to print a list. A list that is an element of a pair is still a list, no different from any other list. Why ever mention pairs?

Comment: `for (auto & str : pair.second){ std::cout << str << '\n';}`

Comment: What does this have to do with pairs?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to print the list in one statement without having to use interators.

There sure is: If, while modifying the list, you maintain an array where you store pointers to each element contained in the list, then you can simply loop over the array to get all the objects. No need for iterators!

A more serious suggestion: Just use iterators. There's no need to use them explicitly, if you use a range based loop.