# C++ pairs, return list inside pair

Tags: c++, list

I have several elements held in a `std::list`. I have to return something like `std::pair<int, std::list<std::string> >`. For the `int` I just add the `int` variable in directly to the `std::pair`. How do you list all the element inside a pair?

Comment: [`.first` and `.second`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair#Member_objects)

Comment: `l = std::list<string>; i = <int type>; return {i, l}; `

Comment: @biscuitlust It's quite unclear what you are *really* asking. How to access the two members of a pair? How to access the members of the list inside the pair? How to construct the pair? Moreover, the title and the question don't match, the title is virtually the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205355/c-return-list-inside-a-stdpair).

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a `std::list<std::string>` just add it in the same.  Alternatively, write:

```
    std::pair<int,std::list<std::string>> result;
    result.second.push_back("first string");
    result.second.push_back("second string");
    ....
```

Comment: what do your mean add it the same?

Comment: std::pair<int,std::list<std::string>>result;  result.first = myint; result.second = mylist;

Comment: Once you start to care about performance, you can use return std::make_pair( myint, mylist );